# Go Language Program error

Tags: go

I am a new Go Language programmer. Below is my program but I am getting this error:

```
#command-line-arguments
    .\helloworld.go:20: undefined: json.Marshall
```

Can anyone tell why I get the error?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

type API struct {
    Message string "json:message"
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/api", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        message := API{"Hello, World!!!"}

        output, err := json.Marshall(message)

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Something went wrong")
        }

        fmt.Fprintf(w, string(output))

    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)

}
```

Comment: I'm no Go expert but a quick look at the API shows that the function is Marshal (one 'l', not two).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output clearly tells you what is your problem.

> undefined: json.Marshall

means that there is no method with this name. On the other side looking at the [documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) the method is called

> func Marshal(v interface{}) ([]byte, error)

So just use a correct name and learn how to debug because debugging is really important in software engineering.

Answer (score 2):

Update your program

```
output, err := json.Marshal(message)
```

(`Marshal` with one `l`, http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal).